# Extract a tuple array in python in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD of the form:

> (2, [hello, hi, how, are, you])

I need to map these tuple like:

> ((2,hello), (2, hi), (2, how), ((2, are), (2, you))

I am trying this in python:

```
PairRDD = rdd.flatMap(lambda (k,v): v.split(',')).map(lambda x: (k,x)).reduceByKey())
```

This will not work as I do not have k in map transformation. I am not sure how to do it ? Any comments ?

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your core issue is a misplaced right parens. Consider the following code (I've tested the equivalent in Scala, but it should work the same way in pySpark):

```
PairRDD = rdd.flatMap(lambda (k,v): v.split(',').map(lambda x: (k,x)))
```

`v` is split into a list of strings, and then that list is mapped to a tuple of (key, string), and then that list is returned to flatMap, splitting it out into multiple rows in the RDD. With the additional right parens after `v.split(',')`, you were throwing away the key (since you only returned a list of strings).

Are the key values unique in the original dataset? If so and you want a list of tuples, then instead of `flatMap` use `map` and you'll get what you want without a shuffle. If you do want to combine multiple rows from the original dataset, then a `groupByKey` is called for, not `reduceByKey`.

I'm also curious if the split is necessary--is your tuple (Int, String) or (Int, List(String))?

Comment: yes, I was doing wrong. Now by placing right parens appropriately i can get the values in (key, value) pair. My rdd here is a zip'ed RDD and before zipping the right part was a list. I checked its type. 
But now after zip, and the placing the bracket appropriately. I can access the key value. But somehow it gives error as list is not iterative while doing v.split(',').  Thanks a lot for help Matthew.

Comment: @rahul If it's a list you don't need to do `split`; you should be able to just do `v.map(lambda x: (k,x))` as `split` is a function that turns a string into a list, and `map` is a function for lists (and other similar objects).

Comment: ok..I did that. So my code looks like: PairRDD = rdd.flatMap(lambda (k,v): v.map(lambda x: (k,x))  . But it gives me error as list object  have no attribute map

Comment: Error is: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'.

Comment: Sorry, I'm too used to Scala, where map is a function of lists rather than a [function that takes a list an an input](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~erdmann/mse350/topics/list_comprehensions.html#map). In Python I think the cleanest way to do it is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), so something like `rdd.map(lambda (k,v): [(k, x) for x in v])` .